# Edit Google Calendar "From" and "Organizer"

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I want to create event via google calendar api using Go. I found out that the sender (From) is whoever responsible in client_id I provide in the google API, in this case me. Can I edit this sender, so that it is not sent from me? At least I can edit the display name of the sender, the email I think will always be my email

Also about editing the organizer, I tried to use move action but it only moves the event, not change the organizer. Is there other way to edit organizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your questions:

***1. Can I create an event from another address?***

**What you want can be done by creating a service account and performing domain-wide-delegation**

*What is a service account?*

A service account is a special type of Google account intended to represent a non-human user that needs to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs - in your situation the Calendar API.

After creating the above mentioned service account, you will have to perform domain-wide-delegation and impersonate a user in your domain in order to be able to create the event wanted.

Now, when writing the code for your application, you will have the use the credentials that were created for this account in order to authorize the requests.

**OR**

If you want to specifically edit only the *display name* of the creator of the event, you can perform an update request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

And add in the request body this:

```
  "creator": {
    "displayName": "UPDATED DISPLAY NAME"
  }
```

***2. Can I edit the organizer?***

According to the [Calendar API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events):

> `organizer`   > The organizer of the event. If the organizer is also an attendee, this is indicated with a separate entry in attendees with the organizer field set to True. To change the organizer, use the move operation. **Read-only, except when importing an event.**

Therefore, the organizer can be changed/updated *only when importing the event* in question.

#### Reference

- [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)
  ;
- [Creating A Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount);
- [Calendar API Events Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource);
- [Calendar API Events:Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).

Comment: I tried to use update action, but the sender display name is still not changed. I received blank email for the update action. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by *sender*? Also, how are you making the request?

Comment: I am making the request using google api go client library, [insert event](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3#EventsService.Insert). 

when someone (A) create calendar event and invite someone (B,C), B and C will get invitation from me (so the sender is me) because the account for google api is my account, even though A is the one that create the event. 

I want that B and C will receive the invitation from A. Is that possible?

Comment: @AldoPratamaLianto, yes, that is possible. You need to create a service account, just like mentioned above, and perform domain wide delegation and impersonate your account.

Comment: as I understand, impersonate my account only works for me. That means every time event is created will be sent by me, not by the real creator. In my case, there are many users who can create an event. Will they be the sender if I use service account?

Comment: You can impersonate any other account from the domain, it doesn't have to be you specifically.

Comment: does that mean I have to delegate every account that will possibly create an event? because I don't know who exactly will create the event, I think any employee will be able to

Comment: Create one service account that will impersonate one specific user and afterwards use that service account to create the event instead of multiple users.